# What is a 'library' file? ie: shared library

Tags: linux, dll, shared-libraries

For example, the description of /lib/ is that it contents shared library files for the system.

What exactly is a library? Are we talking about library files similarly to importing a library in C? What is contained in a library file and what are they used for?

What relation does it have to a .dll

Comment: Read the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 2):

A library is just a block of code, and sometimes data, that can be used by other programs. Objects in a *static* library get physically included in a program's code at linking time, and each program using them will have its own copy. Objects in a *shared* library will be accessed by a program at run time. A `.dll` is just Microsoft's word for a shared library, the equivalent on Linux would usually be `.so`.

Answer (score 1):

A library is a collection of routines that can be called from different programs or libraries. Dynamic (shared) libraries can be loaded at runtime, so the library can be swapped without having to recompile the programs using it. /lib/ contains the libraries available on your operating system, but they don't have to be C libraries.

.dll is the Windows equivalent of shared libraries (.so).